SwiftUI stuck on scrollable transition
I'm trying to build a workout tracking IOS Application. I created a CardView with the most recent workout. Currently it's all dummy data. I'm stuck on a scrollable transition. For reference I added a scene for the kind of functionality I want.
Link to Gif
I tried both using a ScrollView or a ZStack all together. I did find some reference material regarding a Carousel. I thought I could edit it to my needs but it did not work for me.
The code I currently have is as follows:

struct MyWorkoutsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            LinearGradient(colors: [Color("Gradient1"), Color("Gradient2")], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Chest & Back")
                    .font(.rubik(.regular, size: 26))
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
               Text("Mon, May 8")
                    .font(.rubik(.regular, size: 14))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(.systemGray2))
                Spacer()
                
                WorkOutBarChart()
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text("7")
                            .font(.questrial(.questrialRegular, size: 26))
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        Text("times completed")
                            .font(.rubik(.regular, size: 14))
                            .foregroundStyle(Color(.systemGray))
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("START")
                            .font(.rubik(.regular, size: 14))
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .background {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.linearGradient(colors: [Color("Gradient1"), Color("Gradient2")], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                            }
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(height: 300)
    }
}

Image of code above
